# Proper way to refer to COALESCED value in SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I am using the "COALESCE" function in a SELECT statement. What is the proper way to refer to the column value in the JOIN? For example ..

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) 
FROM 
  TableA 
  LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID 
  LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.ID = TableC.ID
  LEFT JOIN TableD ON <COALESCE VALUE HERE> = TableD.Name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would just use `LEFT JOIN TableD ON COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) = TableD.Name`

There's no way to reference an expression from the `SELECT` clause anywhere within the query that clause refers to.

Comment: And this is a sad, sad thing :-)

Comment: @xanatos: The one exception is when sorting, where you can use `ORDER BY 1, 2` to sort by the first column, then the second.

Comment: You refer to the ALIASED name in the ORDER BY clause. It is actually the preferred method nowadays to ordinal position

Comment: I didn't even know of positional ordering! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to expand out the COALESCE, which may work better in certain distributions of data

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) 
FROM 
  TableA 
  LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID 
  LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.ID = TableC.ID
  LEFT JOIN TableD ON (TableA.Name1 = TableD.Name)
                   OR (TableA.Name1 IS NULL AND TableA.Name2 = TableD.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) 
FROM 
  TableA 
  LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID 
  LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.ID = TableC.ID
  LEFT JOIN TableD ON COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) = TableD.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

To what other persons said, I'll add

```
SELECT Base.* FROM
    (SELECT 
        ID,
        COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) Names
        FROM TableA
    ) Base

LEFT JOIN TableB ON Base.ID = TableB.ID 
LEFT JOIN TableC ON Base.ID = TableC.ID
LEFT JOIN TableD ON Base.Names = TableD.Name
```

And as Gabe suggested, with a CTE (I think it's a little overkill a CTE here, and I love using CTEs)

```
; WITH Base AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) Names
        FROM TableA
)

SELECT Base.* From Base
    LEFT JOIN TableB ON Base.ID = TableB.ID 
    LEFT JOIN TableC ON Base.ID = TableC.ID
    LEFT JOIN TableD ON Base.Names = TableD.Name
```

Comment: This leads me to ask ... What is a CTE?

Comment: @webworm: Common Table Expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The obvious ways will work:

```
LEFT JOIN 
        TableD 
ON      COALESCE(TableA.Name1, TableA.Name2) = TableD.Name
```

or:

```
LEFT JOIN 
        TableD 
ON      TableA.Name1 = TableD.Name
        OR TableA.Name2 = TableD.Name
```

(EDIT: the second query won't work, like it says in the comments)

Comment: Your second method will not work as expected when both `Name1` and `Name2` are not null.

Comment: @Gabe: If both are not null, the first two joins ensure `Name1 = Name2`.  So it'll still work :)

Comment: Bad. Bad query. `Name1=A, Name2=B` will match against `TableD.Name=B`. Not desired

Comment: I don't see where you get `Name1 = Name2` from.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: I don't think the first two joins can return a row where `Name1=A, Name2=B`