# Bigquery coalesce join when key is null

Tags: google-bigquery

Table 1

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| user_id | email     | action |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 1       | aa@aa.com | open   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 2       | null      | click  |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 3       | ac@ac.com | click  |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 4       | ad@ad.com | open   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Table 2

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| user_id | email     | event  |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 1       | aa@aa.com | sent   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| null    | ac@ac.com | none   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 2       | ab@ab.com | sent   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 4       | ad@ad.com | sent   |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to join based on t1.user_id = t2.user_id, but when there is a null for the key, join on t1.email = t2.email

I tried multiple ways to JOIN in bigquery as:
1.)ON COALESCE(t1.user_id,t1.email) = COALESCE(t2.user_id, t2.email)
2.)ON on case when t2.user_id is not null then t1.user_id = t2.user_id else t1.email = t2.email end

Neither work.  How can this be done?

Comment: SQL has "IS DISTINCT" and "IS NOT DISTINCT" but I don't see that in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split such join to two separate:
First - join by user_id

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Second - join by email for those ids missed in first join

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM table1
  WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT t1.user_id
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  )
) t1
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM table2
  WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT t1.user_id
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  )
) t2
ON t1.email = t2.email
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was really hoping it use COALESCE.  It appears possible based on the link.  But, not supported by BigQuery I guess?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304184/proper-way-to-refer-to-coalesced-value-in-select-statement

Comment: per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#query-grammar : join_predicate:
    field_from_one_side_of_the_join = field_from_the_other_side_of_the_join [ AND ...]